# TFDTable de FireDAC con Oracle

Tags: oracle

Estoy trabajando con Delphi XE7 con su característica FireDAC con conexión a una base de datos de Oracle, he notado que al utilizar el componente TFDTable se agrega la columna ROWID, ¿saben cual es el uso de esta columna en el TFDTable? ¿esta columna genera algún problema con la utilidad de TFDTable?, de ser así ¿cual es la configuración para evitar que TFDTable no la tome en cuenta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ROWID` es una pseudo-columna](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) que Oracle crea en todas las tablas y que usualmente no es *visible* para el usuario.

Lo que está ocurriendo es que FireDAC, al no ser una capa de conexión *especializada* en Oracle, la está viendo como una columna normal y por eso te la muestra (cosa que a mi forma de ver no debiera hacer).

Mi recomendación es simplemente ignorarla, pues no es una columna que te vaya a ser útil, simplemente existe. Es algo como un *detalle de implementación* de cómo Oracle en particular gestiona el modelo relacional.

Si estás creando campos persistentes puedes, de hecho, eliminar el campo (dentro de la `FDTable` en tu aplicación Delphi) para no verlo por allí.

Si tienes curiosidad, la columna `ROWID` tiene una especie de *apuntador* a la dirección física de un registro en particular dentro de la base de datos.

Generalmente puedes hacer algo como:

```
select RowID, OtroCampo
  from MiTabla;
```